# Does this Java program need to be two separate Files

Tags: java

Hi everyone I am taking a Java class and this is my first assignment involving object oriented programming. I am getting issues with the SimpleCalc portion and am wondering if my work should be two separate files or if I am missing a component that allows the StatCalc part and SimpleCalc part to speak with one another. Please keep in mind that I am new to Java so I might need this spelled out a bit more then I have seen on stack over flow in the past at times, however, I will appreciate any help so thank you in advance. Here is my code:

```
package tutorial; 
/*   
* An object of class StatCalc can be used to compute several simple statistics  
* for a set of numbers.  Numbers are entered into the dataset using  
* the enter(double) method.  Methods are provided to return the following  
* statistics for the set of numbers that have been entered: The number  
* of items, the sum of the items, the average, the standard deviation,  
* the maximum, and the minimum.  
*/ public class StatCalc {

           private int count;   // Number of numbers that have been entered.
           private double sum;  // The sum of all the items that have been entered.
           private double squareSum;  // The sum of the squares of all the items.        
           private double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;                               private double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
           /**
            * Add a number to the dataset.  The statistics will be computed for all
            * the numbers that have been added to the dataset using this method.
            */
           public void enter(double num) {
                  count++;
                  sum += num;
                  squareSum += num*num;               
                  if (count == 1){
                      max = num;
                      min = num;
                  }
                  else {
                      if (num > max)
                          max = num;
                      if (num < min)
                          min = num;
                  }     
           }
           /**

            * Return the number of items that have been entered into the dataset.

            */

           public int getCount() {

                  return count;
           }
           /**

            * Return the sum of all the numbers that have been entered.

            */

           public double getSum() {

                  return sum;
           }         
           /**

            * Return the average of all the items that have been entered.

            * The return value is Double.NaN if no numbers have been entered.

           */

           public double getMean() {

                  return sum / count;
           }     

           /**

            * Return the standard deviation of all the items that have been entered.

            * The return value is Double.NaN if no numbers have been entered.

            */

           public double getStandardDeviation() {

                  double mean = getMean();

                  return Math.sqrt( squareSum/count - mean*mean );
           }

           public double getMin(){
               return min;
           }
           public double getMax(){
               return max;
           }        }// end class StatCalc

public class SimpleCalc {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        SimpleCalc calc;
        calc = new SimpleCalc();

        double item;
        System.out.println("Enter numbers here. Enter 0 to stop.");       
        System.out.println();

        do{ 
            System.out.print("? ");
            item = in.nextDouble();

            if (item != 0)
                calc.enter(item);
        }while (item != 0);

        System.out.println("\nStatistics about your calc:\n");   
        System.out.println(Count: "+calc.getCount"()); 
        System.out.println(Sum: "+calc.getSum"());   
        System.out.println("Minimum: "+calc.getMin());  
        System.out.println("Maximum: "+calc.getMax());  
        System.out.println("Average: "+calc.getMean());     
        System.out.println("Standard Deviation: "+calc.getStandardDeviation());     
    }// end main
}//end SimpleCalc
```

Comment: Sorry about that I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it needs two files.

Java's contract is that every "top level" public class requires it's own file.

Comment: That's the difference between a "top level" class and an inner class.  Inner classes do not follow the same rules!

Comment: Yes, but `StatCalc` could be a inner class of `SimpleCalc`.  I think you need to clarify "top level".  And the last time I checked, you could have package private class with a `public static void main` and it would still work...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, it could be an inner class, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In Java a public class must be in a file with the same name as the class. So since you have a public class named StatCalc then the filename must be StatCalc.java. Similarly the second class is also public therefore it must be in its own file.

Comment: Ah that makes complete sense. So I tried having two separate files, but was seeing online that I would use scanner in order to have the two recognize each other and when I would follow the steps I would see I still could not fix the problem. What is the proper way to have two files see each other? I am not sure that my teacher ever properly explained it nor if the two files can be in the same package, same src, etc.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Lets not get too picky as the OP seems to be struggling with some basic syntax. The example you cited involves nested static classes. While absolutely correct I don't think that helps with this question.

Comment: @JerFlip Not sure what you are asking here. What do you mean by recognize each other? If the two files are in the same directory and both in the same package then they should just "see" each other if you try to reference one from the other.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie Maybe not, but the statement *"In Java a public class must"* is false and erroneous...

Comment: So if both files are in the same package then they should see each other without me needing to include anything in my java files themselves? I guess I am just unsure because in the past my instructor would have use use TextIO files and text files so I was not sure if the same steps apply or not.

Comment: I think I found what you were referring to, which is for me to add a constructor and tell each file that one file extends to the other so that when I compile Java will know to look at the other file. Let me know if I am off base with this thought though. Thanks!